# how do i add checkbox in my gridview?

Tags: android

this is my code below which used simple adapter please just tellme how do i add checkbox in my code? so user select many pic using checkbox and perform action like delete? please help me pleaseee help me i want to add checkbox in my gridview im using simple adapter which is default android adapter what do i do? how do i modify??? what do i do????

```
    File root1;
 String filePath;
     File currentParent;
     File[] currentFiles;
     GridView gridView;

        File photos = new File(getFilesDir(), "Photos");
    photos.mkdirs();

    root1 = new File("/data/data/com.myexample.folder/files/");

    currentParent = root1;
    currentFiles = root1.listFiles();

    currentFilePath = new String[currentFiles.length];
    int count = 0;

    for (File f : currentFiles) {
        currentFilePath[count] = f.getAbsolutePath();
        count++;
    }

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,   
                      int position, long id) {



            if (currentFiles[position].isDirectory()) {

                root = new File("/data 
  /data/com.myexample.folder/files/"+ FileName(currentFilePath[position]) + "/");

textView.setText(FileName(currentFilePath[position]));
                Log.e("Root first", root + " ");

                currentFiles = root.listFiles();

                inflateListView(currentFiles);
            } else if (currentFiles[position].isFile()) {

                openFile(currentFiles[position]);


            }}});


                private void inflateListView(File[] files) {


    List<Map<String, Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {


            listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
            listItem.put("fileName", files[i].getName()+"(" 
                               +files[i].list().length+")");
        } else {



        //  
            listItem.put("icon", files[i]);

        }


        listItems.add(listItem);
    }

    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.line,new 
                      String[] { "icon", "fileName" }, new int[] { R.id.icon,
                    R.id.file_name });

    gridView.invalidateViews();
    gridView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



  }
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: i wanna add checkbox in my code so select many images using checkbox

Comment: im using simple adapter in my code so how do i customise simpleadapter or add checkbox in my code???

Comment: Yes, I get that is what you want to do, However have you tried to do it yourself before asking for help?

Comment: yes to many i see this tutorial http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/    but he is load from gallery im load from directory

Comment: please help mee what do i do

Answer (score 0):

[The android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) has a very good list of widgets, what they do, and their names. It's good to learn how to use documentation!

To answer your question, though, [this is the page for checkboxes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html)

Comment: ur link nor h3lp me i want to add  checkbox in gridview